# how applied styles to each ListItem Native-base

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I have a array so:

```
const routes = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Home', image: 'home', cstyle: 'styles.ItemsDrawer' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Chat', image: 'flask', cstyle: 'styles.ItemsDrawer' },
  { id: 3, title: 'Profile', image: 'briefcase', cstyle: 'styles.ItemsDrawer' },
  { id: 5, title: 'Logout', image: 'log-out', cstyle: 'styles.logout' }
];
```

and want applied to some items a style different,

```
<List dataArray={routes}
   renderRow={(data) =>
   <ListItem style={data.cstyle} 
     button onPress={() => ctx.navigate(data.title)} icon> 
   </ListItem>}>
</List>
```

but i thinked that passing "data.cstyle" it would take a name and try found it style in section stylesheet, but this does not recognize and leave without styles to each item from list dynamic

or how would applied different styles to some items from list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To apply different styles for each `<ListItem/>` in a `<List/>`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Container, Header, Content, List, ListItem, Text } from 'native-base';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  itemOne: { backgroundColor: 'red', marginLeft: 0 },
  itemTwo: { backgroundColor: 'blue', marginLeft: 0 },
  itemThree: { backgroundColor: 'green', marginLeft: 0 },
  itemFour: { backgroundColor: 'violet', marginLeft: 0 },

})
const routes = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Home', image: 'home', cstyle: styles.itemOne },
  { id: 2, title: 'Chat', image: 'flask', cstyle: styles.itemTwo },
  { id: 3, title: 'Profile', image: 'briefcase', cstyle: styles.itemThree },
  { id: 5, title: 'Logout', image: 'log-out', cstyle: styles.itemFour }
];
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <List dataArray={routes}
            renderRow={(data) =>
              <ListItem style={data.cstyle}
                button icon><Text>{data.id}. {data.title}</Text>
              </ListItem>}>
          </List>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

Image

[image]